# Проблема с проверкой хэша пароля пользователя при авторизации на PHP

Tags: php

при проверке пароля зарегистрированного пользователя возникает ошибка-пароль неверный, хотя ввожу его корректно. Просьба помочь с кодом проверки хэша пароля, думаю ошибка в нем, но не могу найти где именно. Код файла логина и файла регистрации прилагаю.

```php
Регистрация
<?php

require_once "config.php";
require_once "session.php";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $fullname = trim($_POST['name']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    $confirm_password = trim($_POST["confirm_password"]);
    $password_hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

    if($query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?")) {
        $error = '';
        // Bind parameters (s = string, i = int, b = blob, etc), in our case the username is a string so we use "s"
    $query->bind_param('s', $email);
    $query->execute();
    // Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.
    $query->store_result();
        if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
            $error .= '<p class="error">The email address is already registered!</p>';
        } else {
            // Validate password
            if (strlen($password ) < 6) {
                $error .= '<p class="error">Password must have atleast 6 characters.</p>';
            }

            // Validate confirm password
            if (empty($confirm_password)) {
                $error .= '<p class="error">Please enter confirm password.</p>';
            } else {
                if (empty($error) && ($password != $confirm_password)) {
                    $error .= '<p class="error">Password did not match.</p>';
                }
            }
            if (empty($error) ) {
                $insertQuery = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?);");
                $insertQuery->bind_param("sss", $fullname, $email, $password_hash);
                $result = $insertQuery->execute();
                if ($result) {
                    $error .= '<p class="success">Your registration was successful!</p>';
                } else {
                    $error .= '<p class="error">Something went wrong!</p>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $query->close();
    $insertQuery->close();
    // Close DB connection
    mysqli_close($db);
}
?>

Логин

<?php

require_once "config.php";
require_once "session.php";


$error = '';
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);

    // validate if email is empty
    if (empty($email)) {
        $error .= '<p class="error">Please enter email.</p>';
    }

    // validate if password is empty
    if (empty($password)) {
        $error .= '<p class="error">Please enter your password.</p>';
    }

    if (empty($error)) {
        if($query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?")) {
            $query->bind_param('s', $email);
            $query->execute();
            $row = $query->fetch();
            if ($row) {
                if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
                    $_SESSION["userid"] = $row['id'];
                    $_SESSION["user"] = $row;

                    // Redirect the user to welcome page
                    header("location: welcome.php");
                    exit;
                } else {
                    $error .= '<p class="error">The password is not valid.</p>';
                }
            } else {
                $error .= '<p class="error">No User exist with that email address.</p>';
            }
        }
        $query->close();
    }
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($db);
}
?>
```

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский
Код проверял на валидаторе, ошибок нет. Что-то не так с самим составом кода.

Comment: На каком валидаторе? Есть ещё отладка........ рабочий инструмент

Comment: `$query->fetch()` возвращает не то что ты ожидаешь. [Мануал здесь](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.fetch-returnvalues)

Comment: @u_mulder
Подскажите как поправить, пожалуйста.

Comment: @u_mulder Спасибо, но к сожалению так и не получается исправить.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, если у меня php не на компе, а на хостинге только, как дебажить? Я новичок в php, буду признателен если подскажите что не так с кодом.

Comment: @EvgeniyR1987 вообще, как минимум на хостинге есть логи и надо смотреть туда.... Во-вторых - прежде чем лить на хост - надо всё отточить локально.... .. Если локально всё было идеально, то скорее всего разница с хостом есть.. Как правило ошибки в логах на это укажут..... А так, если логов не хватает и нужно прям дебажить - поищите удалённая отладка php phpstorm к примеру. То есть сама процедура тоже реальна

Comment: @u-mulder, Вы же знаете в чем причина, поделитесь пожалуйста.